# Movie about woman seeing a dog bigger and bigger as the plot progresses

Tags: story-identification

I barely remember a few things about a movie I watched when I was a kid (the plot is not for kids though!), and I'd like to see if somebody can help me find it:

- The main characters are a mom and her son
- one way or another, a dog (may be a rottweiler) is an important character of the story
- the mom is particularly concerned about the dog's aggressiveness
- the mom starts seeing the dog bigger and bigger as the movie goes on (which makes it ok to classify the movie at least partly fantasy???)
- towards the end of the movie the dog is as big as a house, and I kinda remember that it literally grows so big while inside the house, thus taking the roof off the house
- afterwards the woman is shown in a hospital or a psychiatric unit, with the mark of some kind of lobotomy on her forehead.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: @LogicDictates, it might be older than 2000. Surely older than 2005.

Comment: The basic premise sounds a little like "There's no Such Thing as a Dragon", but of course that's a charming illustrated children's book.

Comment: @Showsni, I've clarified that the movie is not for kids.